# pythonically looping through substrings

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a substring:

```
a="this is a really big long string which i am going to print substrings from"
```

and I want to print it, then print a[0:-6]; a[0:-12]; a[0:-18]; etc until the substring being printed is empty. Part of why i like python so much is that you can generally make your loops look nicer than they do in other languages, but I can't think of a way of doing this pythonically.

Comment: So the substring is has always the same size?

Comment: no it's loosing 6 characters at each step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all answers here are equel in core, let me give some brief explanation on the steps done.
When speaking of pythonian way of doing things, most of the time (of course not exclusively) `list comprehension` is meant.
In your case, you can utilize it as following:
With

```
[a[i] for i in range(0,len(a),1)]
```

you can iterate over every single character in the string. If you wanted to always have substrings of length 6 it would be

```
[a[i:i+6] for i in range(0,len(a)-6,1)]
```

NOTICE: That you need to care about the upper bound of the string ````len(a)-6```

````
Since you want your substring to always start at position 0 we fixate it with ```
a[0:...]
````

Lastly we use i to go from the end `len(a)` to the start `0` by steps of `-6`

```
a="this is a really big long string which i am going to print substrings from"

[a[0:i] for i in range(len(a),0,-6)]

-->
['this is a really big long string which i am going to print substrings from',
 'this is a really big long string which i am going to print substring',
 'this is a really big long string which i am going to print sub',
 'this is a really big long string which i am going to pri',
 'this is a really big long string which i am going ',
 'this is a really big long string which i am ',
 'this is a really big long string which',
 'this is a really big long string',
 'this is a really big long ',
 'this is a really big',
 'this is a real',
 'this is ',
 'th']
```

Now that returns a list of the substrings. If you want to print them directly, we use another trick, that is

```
def func(a, b, c):
  [...]

l = [a, b, c]

func(*l) == func(a, b, c)
```

We can use the asterix `*` to unpack a list to pass arguments to a functions, so we can also pass each substring in the list to the `print` function. However, by default the seperatur of print is a space, so we need to change that with `sep=\n"`

```
print(*[a[0:i] for i in range(len(a),0,-6)],sep="\n")
```

```
print(*[a[0:i] for i in range(len(a),0,-6)],sep="\n")
this is a really big long string which i am going to print substrings from
this is a really big long string which i am going to print substring
this is a really big long string which i am going to print sub
this is a really big long string which i am going to pri
this is a really big long string which i am going 
this is a really big long string which i am 
this is a really big long string which
this is a really big long string
this is a really big long 
this is a really big
this is a real
this is 
th
```

Comment: this is the reverse of what she wants, and it doesn't print the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
a = "this is a really big long string which i am going to print substrings from"

for i in range(0, -len(a), -6):
    b = a[:i]
    print(b)
```

Output:

```
this is a really big long string which i am going to print substring
this is a really big long string which i am going to print sub
this is a really big long string which i am going to pri
this is a really big long string which i am going 
this is a really big long string which i am 
this is a really big long string which
this is a really big long string
this is a really big long 
this is a really big
this is a real
this is 
th
```

Here is a list comprehension method:

```
a = "this is a really big long string which i am going to print substrings from"

print('\n'.join(a[:i] for i in range(0, -len(a), -6)))
```

Comment: I guess, thats what he wanted to avoid

Comment: @FloLie A loop can also be pythonic, they didn't say no loops.

Comment: Why not just unpack the list using `*` and `print()` using seperator newline?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
print(*reversed([a[0:x] for x in range(0,len(a)-6,6)]),sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
this is a really big long string which i am going to print substri
this is a really big long string which i am going to print s
this is a really big long string which i am going to p
this is a really big long string which i am goin
this is a really big long string which i a
this is a really big long string whi
this is a really big long stri
this is a really big lon
this is a really b
this is a re
this i
```